# Ajax Control Toolkit Slider Handler Image Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, sliderextender

like the title says, i am using ajax control toolkit SliderExtender . Everything works fine but not the styling of the control. I am using this code in aspx page

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBoxSlider"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:SliderExtender Orientation="Horizontal" ID="sliderExtenderControl" TargetControlID="textBoxSlider" HandleCssClass="handleClass" RailCssClass="railClass" EnableHandleAnimation="True" runat="server"></asp:SliderExtender>
```

and the CSS classes :

```
.handleClass {
    width: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #455f47;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #5e5e5e, #8f8f8f);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #5e5e5e, #8f8f8f);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5e5e5e, #8f8f8f);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #5e5e5e, #8f8f8f);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5e5e5e, #8f8f8f);
}

.railClass {
    width: 450px;
    height: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #61bb46;
    position: relative;
}
```

and i have an image for slider handler with height : 18px and width 44px .

The control looks like this :
[image: slider]

what i am trying to do but without success is to align the handle image slightly higher so that the rail will be in the middle of the handler. Also i want that the left side of the slider to be a some color and the right side some other color and this colors will change on slider dragging. i think this could be done with some javascript.

In the end i would like the slider to look something like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the sliding js for the component looks like and if it changes the top position for the handle. If it does not change, you can add this to .handleClass

```
top:-5px;
```

If you want to make colors change, you must have another div over the handle with opacity:0, which changes it's transparency as the handle moves right. If you supply some the handle js, maybe I can add some code.